# Getting certain Table reference of String to use in jSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I would like to use jSoup to get the time from this webpage... The time I need is the "11:19" in the red bar near the top... http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsRace.aspx?raceID=293047-2

Does anybody know how I would use jSoup to get this from the webpage? If anyone has any advice on how to locate elements within tables in future, please could you let me know.

Also, I need to get the "View Race" link address from this table: http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=Ballymac%20Monleek, but when I currently get that element, it just gives me "View Race" rather than the actual link...

```
 //getHistory
    String dogPage = "http://www.gbgb.org.uk/raceCard.aspx?dogName=" + selectedDog;
    Document doc1 = Jsoup.connect(dogPage).get();

    Element tblHeader = doc1.select("table.MasterTable_Web20 tbody").first();
    List<DogDetail> data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Element element1 : tblHeader.children()){

        String webURL = (element1.select("td:eq(14)").text());
        System.out.println(webURL);
    }
```

Thanks,

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one very quick way to do it (probably not the best, but it works, I just tested it).

Using chrome, it's very easy to get an XPath expression for every single element in a webpage (right clicks text, "inspect", copy XPath expression). In this case, it's :

```
 //*[@id="content"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[4]
```

Now, if the page structure never ever changes, that may be enough. Use the [Xsoup extension](https://github.com/code4craft/xsoup) to use XPath expressions with Jsoup:

```
        Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://www.gbgb.org.uk/resultsRace.aspx?raceID=293047-2").get(); 
        XElements element = Xsoup.compile("//*[@id=\"content\"]/table[2]/tbody/tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table[1]/tbody/tr/td[4]").evaluate(document);

        // Get text content
        String textContent = element.getElements().get(0).childNode(0).toString();

        // Extract time portion
        String time = textContent.trim().replaceAll("\\&nbsp\\;", " ").split("\\s+")[1];

        // Prints 11:19
        System.out.println(time);
```

Of course, be warned, this is very sensitive to possible future changes in the structure of the page.

For the second part of your question, you get this set of xpaths

```
*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00__0"]/td[15]/a
*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00__1"]/td[15]/a
*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00__2"]/td[15]/a
...
*[@id="ContentPlaceHolder1_RadGrid1_ctl00__15"]/td[15]/a
```

A simple iteration would easily get them all.

Comment: Hi, How do I use XSoup? I have downloaded it but not sure where to put it/how to use it? Thanks for your help

Comment: Either use maven, or download the jar from there and add it in your project classpath: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/us.codecraft/xsoup/0.3.0

Comment: Thanks, thats working perfectly. For the second part of the question - would you be able to show me an example please of how to iterate through? Thanks